# ui-route resolve not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

My Application needs a some basic data to start. That's why i created a service and I am using it as model for that common data so that it can be accessible to all the controllers. I am trying to resolve the service using ui-route's reslove functionality that says if I return a promise then it will be resolved before the controller's execution begin but it is not working for me. here is my code

service:

```
var Data = function ($q, $http) {
var list = {};
var cachedData;
var resolveData;

resolveData = function () {
    return $http.get('/api/data')
        .then(function (response) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            deferred.resolve(list.setData(response.data));

            return deferred.promise;
        }, function (response) {
        });
};

list.getData = function () {
    if (cachedData) {
        return cachedData;
    }
    else {
        resolveData();
    }
};

list.setData = function (data) {

    cachedData = data;

    return data;
};
return list;
};

Data.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];
```

Route:

```
.state('temp', {
        url: 'temp',
        templateUrl: '/temp',
        controller: 'temp',
        resolve: {
            data: function (data) {
                return data.getData();
            }
        }
    })
```

Controller:

```
var temp = function(data, $scope){
    console.log('asad');
    $scope.showLoading = true;

    $scope.prefixes = data.something; //not working

    $scope.lists = data;
};

temp.$inject = ['data', '$scope'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, it will be easier to work with a plunker.

But it seems like the function getData doesn't return any promise.

I will change getData() to something like:

```
list.getData = function () {
var deferred = $q.defer();
if (cachedData) {
    deferred.resolve(cachedData);
} else {
    resolveData().then(deferred.resolve).catch(deferred.reject);
}

return deferred.promise;
};
```

btw, I will also change resolveData() to:

```
resolveData = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/api/data')
        .then(function (response) {
            list.setData(response.data);
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: Yes you do, that's why resolveData() returns a promise while getData() don't, I've edited my answer with an example of getData().
Please try it and see if it helps you.