# using resolve doesnot change state : Angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i m using angular ui-router and to get data before initiating Controller m using resolve

```
.state('Equipment', {
                url: "/equipment",
                templateUrl: "/Scripts/app/equipment/templates/content.html",
                resolve: {
                    equipmentService: 'EquipmentService',
                    data: function (equipmentService) {
                        return equipmentService.getEquipment().$promise;
                    }
                },
                controller: 'EquipmentController'
            })
```

and in equipmentService i m doing

```
resource.equipment.getEquipment().$promise.then(function (response) {

            _equipment.collection = _.map(response.data, function (item) {
                var obj = {
                    id: item.id,
                    name: item.name,
                    groupId: item.equipmentGroupId,
                    groupName: item.equipmentGroupName,
                    description: item.description
                }
                return obj;
            });
            return _equipment.collection;
        });
```

on response from server service object gets updated but state doesn't change neither controller gets initiated

and if i change it with

```
 return resource.equipment.getEquipment();
```

now on server response controller gets initiated 
but service doesnt as i m using service to share data between controllers. i have to update service object literal

can some one help me what i m doing wrong

Comment: Is that solution working for you ?

Comment: well not i wanted service to resolve its promise and after completing i should be able to change state .  in ur provided answer i have to move all of the code from service to resolve

Comment: I don't think you understand my code. Resolve remains the same in my case too. It's the changes in service  you need to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better option here. You can use this service as a model once the data is retrieved from the server and for that define a variable(property) in service. check out the following question. [ui-route resolve not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668509/ui-route-resolve-not-working)